# Do people use "phising" as a real term, or just a mistaken spelling of "phishing"

Tags: phishing, terminology

Is "phising" a commonly accepted term, or just a mis-spelling of "phishing"?

I've always understood "phishing" is a common security term. However, recently I've started seeing serious articles and people using the word "phising" (without the second h) as if they are serious.

For example, this entire page:
`http://ferruh.mavituna.com/ssl-implementation-security-faq-oku/` [link is now dead]

or this SO question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365294/is-redirecting-http-to-https-a-bad-idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a misspelling. Even in both links.

> phishing ([M-W Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Phishing))
>
> 1. a scam by which an e-mail user is duped into revealing personal or confidential information which the scammer can use illicitly

Might not be the *best* proof, but only 1.2% of all the Google results are for "phising" versus "phishing". I seriously believe this is human err. Furthermore, this is a relativity *newer* term, so it makes sense for things like this to happen.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Another example from [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=phising%2C+phishing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cphising%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphishing%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

So we can infer that "phising" was actually a word in the past, and "phishing" was only invented in 1980. However I'm not sure if this chart is reliable or not.